# main.js:149 Uncaught TypeError: L.easyButton is not a function, Leaflet Button not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have currently a map and am trying to create a Leaflet Easy button that toggles if the `info__container` shows or not. I have also tried display = 'none' but nothing happens.

Currently getting this issue

> Uncaught TypeError: L.easyButton is not a function

I have also made sure that the L.easy Button files are after the main leaflet.js

```
        <!--map required links-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>

        <!--map plugin to locate user-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol@0.79.0/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol@0.79.0/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        
        <!--easy button plugin-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
```

This is my JS

```
var informationBar = document.getElementById(info__container);


var toggle = L.easyButton({
    states: [{
    stateName: 'add-markers',
    icon: '<span class="star">&equiv;</span>',
    title: 'Menu',
    onClick: function(control) {
        map.addLayer(informationBar);
        control.state('remove-markers');
    }
    }, {
    icon: 'fa-undo',
    stateName: 'remove-markers',
    onClick: function(control) {
        map.removeLayer(informationBar);
        control.state('add-markers');
    },
    title: 'remove markers'
    }]
});
toggle.addTo(map);
```

my HTML div start

```
<div id="info__container">
    <table class="tableContainer">
        <tbody>
         <!--Title-->
```

my css

```
#info__container{ 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 800;
    margin-top: 10%; /*change for mobile*/
    margin-left: 5rem;
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 250px;
}
```

I'm a newbie so please bear with me

I have tried different types of functions using map methods or just normal function `onclick`:

this said I have also tried `.toggle()`

Comment: You didn't add the easy button script;

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>

Comment: I don't see the JS code for the definition of **`L`**. If `L` is not defined, then you will get the error *L.easyButton is not a function* => `"undefined".easyButton` does not exist.

Comment: Hi, it’s a leaflet map so it should recognise L as part of it. The 1st comment helped displaying it but still having issues with the function itself